# How do I find out what JavaScript is executed from an HTML input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a problem I think we all struggle with from time to time: you have to work with somebody else's code base that implements an HTML page using "non-intrusive JavaScript" techniques. You have an HTML form, and you know that when you click the button or change the input field, some kind of JavaScript is being invoked. What are your favorite debugging techniques for finding out what is invoked?

*Edit to clarify question*: Example: here's the kind of HTML I have:

```
<select name="attr-1234" class="full primary">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

Looking at the HTML, there are no event handlers. Somewhere in JavaScript code is buried something along the lines of one of these:

```
$('[name^=attr]').select(handleSelection);
$('select[name^=attr]').select(handleSelection);
$('select').select(handleSelection);
$('.full').select(handleSelection);
$('select.full').select(handleSelection);
$('[class*=full]').select(handleSelection);
$('[name^=attr]').change(handleSelection);
$('[name^=attr]').on('select', handleSelection);
... etc. ...
```

I am looking for good ways people have found to figure out what function (here, handleSelection) will be invoked when the selection is changed. Keep in mind that this is a mature project with hundreds of JavaScript and HTML files, so a brute force file-by-file examination is not going to be very efficient.

Chrome Developer Tools, for example, provides an "Event Listeners" that lists a number of events. Unfortunately, when you are dealing with libraries like jQuery UI, this is not nearly as useful as it could be, because all the handlers are inside those libraries. Are there better tools out there?

Answer (score 0):

I usually debug writing some console.log("") in each ramification, "thing" I want to. Example:

```
function clicked (event){
     if (foo == "foo"){
         console.log("foo = foo!");
         //<--- your code
     } else {
         console.log("foo != foo!");
         //<----- your code
     }
}
```

I usually do this when errors appear on dev console to see where is the ***** bug

Comment: * bug? say "*$#& BUG!" it is best to express your anger in full, don't accumulate it

Comment: It's not so much that. I will fix the question to make it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: `==` or `===`, not `=`.